# Jquery selecting the data from the text boxes inside a table?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

```
  function setdata() {
            var info = [];
            $("tr").each(function(trIdx, element) {
                $("td.input").each(function(trId, element) {
                    info.push(input.text);
                });
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "pdtentry.aspx/Done",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ arr: info }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {
                    alert('Yay! It worked!');
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert('Oh no :(');
                }
            });


            return false;

        }
```

the data from the text boxes are not selected .the view of the table from where the data is to be selected is available at: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6PdQG/

2.How to retrieve the values in array in c#?

Comment: Where are you getting the variable `input` from, there's no such thing in that code, so `input.text` is simply an error

Comment: Should be `info.push( $(element).text() );`

Comment: how to retrieve these values in c#